# How to scatter an image with random size, position, and rotation, without using a pattern fill? (ie, no instance is cut off)

Tags: photoshop

Let's say you have an image such as this...

[image: a finished bush]

... and you want to quickly and easily scatter it around to create foliage. How would you achieve this aside from using a pattern fill or pattern stamp tool? (Both of which have the problem of abrupt edges.)
[image: not the result I'm looking for]

This is the sort of result I'm looking for, where none of the instances have cut-off edges, but in a way that doesn't involve me manually copying, scaling, and rotating each and every one.
[image: the result I'm looking for]

If there is a way to either paint this with a brush, or even simply click to stamp these where each click results in a single instance of the image randomly scaled and rotated, that would be amazing.

After having used PS my whole life, this is the first time I've needed to do this, and I am baffled that it doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: This can be be done with a brush and a pressure sensitive stylus (such as a Wacom tablet)  In Brush Settings change the Scatter, Axes, Count & Count Jitter as well Pen Tilt. The alternative is to place them individually by hand, or write a script to do something similar.

Comment: No because the brush only uses a greyscale image as the brush tip. It cannot use an RBG image as a brush.

Comment: If that's quite what you're after try tubes/ image hose with Paint Shop Pro or Corel Painter